# Deleting multiple table view sections with individual animations for each section

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Just like "Wi-Fi" in the iPhone "Settings" app, I have a table view where a switch in the first section toggles whether or not the following sections are displayed.

I've got it working successfully by using `insertSections: withRowAnimation:` and `deleteSections: withRowAnimation:` after updating `tableView: numberOfRowsInSection:`.  However, unlike "Wi-Fi" in "Settings", all deleted sections collapse *together* before fading away.

I would like to achieve the same effect as in "Wi-Fi", where sections collapse within themselves *individually* when they are removed from view.

What's the recommended way to do this?

Comment: Aren't you just talking about changing the row animation? Maybe to something like `UITableViewRowAnimationTop`?

Comment: Hi David, I've tried all the animation styles.  They all collapse sections together, rather than individually.  Also, `UITableViewRowAnimationFade` is the only one that fades out the sections after collapsing.

Comment: What happens if you batch animate (between [myTableView beginUpdates]; and [myTableView removeUpdates];) deleting the all the rows with a suitable row animation and the section with a ...RowAnimationFade?

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think that will get me an error for trying to delete a section that exists after the update, since I need the sections to exist to delete the rows in them?  (I may end up having to update the table view data source in two separate steps.  Just wondering if there's an easier way of achieving the effect that I'm unaware of.)

Comment: I meant do all in one delete but animate it as deletion of both all the cells in that section and the section it self. The data should match since there will be one less section in your data model afterwards

Comment: Hi David, I just gave it a try (`beginUpdates` --> `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths withRowAnimation:` --> `deleteSections: withRowAnimation:` --> `endUpdates`... is that what you meant?) and the end effect was the same as just deleting the sections.  Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: Sorry that it didn't work. Yeah, that was what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it calling `deleteSections` per section:

```
static int nos = 4;

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return nos;
}

-(IBAction)onFadeTableButton:(id)sender
{
    NSMutableIndexSet *sectionsToDelete = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
    [sectionsToDelete addIndex:3];

    nos = 3;
    [self.tableView deleteSections:sectionsToDelete
                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

    [sectionsToDelete addIndex:2];
    [sectionsToDelete removeIndex:3];
    nos = 2;
    [self.tableView deleteSections:sectionsToDelete
                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];


    [sectionsToDelete addIndex:1];
    [sectionsToDelete removeIndex:2];
    nos = 1;
    [self.tableView deleteSections:sectionsToDelete
                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];

    [sectionsToDelete addIndex:0];
    [sectionsToDelete removeIndex:1];
    nos = 0;
    [self.tableView deleteSections:sectionsToDelete
                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];

}
```

The code is ugly cause i was quickly using an existing project (table view with 4 sections), but the idea must be clear. Don't use it as it is, make it beautiful, please.

Comment: Yeah, I thought I might end up having to update the table view data source in multiple steps and delete the sections in succesion of each other.  I'm still curious if there is a simpler way to get the effect, so I'll keep the question open for now.  Thanks for the reply, I'll accept your answer if no better solutions are suggested.

Comment: @James no problem, one note - with that code the sections are removed concurrently (ok, there must be a lag, but visually they are - the next animation doesn't wait until the previous is finished) like in the wi-fi app. And for the cases when i need to hide/show something i prefer to use an additional flags datasource instead of reallocating the data-having datasource - saves a lot of time to me, but that's up to you.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what you mean by additional flags? Thanks again.

Comment: @James sure, the most straightforward way is to prepare to arrays: one has the sections data and another just boolean flags via NSNumber, then i'm calculating the positive flags count at `numberOfSections` instead of the original datasource count. Doing this i need to reset the flag instead of clearing the original datasource and reallocate it when the section needs to be shown again. The solution naturally comes to optimize the complex datasource with a large preparation time, but it needs additional logic to change the ds/flags synchronously to avoid the logic collisions.

Comment: In the more beautiful manner i would prepare a special section class containing the rows data, hide/show flag, maybe some sorting and display mode flags, whatever you need. Hm, i need to collect all this ideas into the framework :)